# Wait for submit to explode data in php

Tags: php, forms, input, explode

So I'm basically trying to wait for the user to input a series of numbers before exploding them into an array. Its attempting to explode the data before it is actually entered so I'm getting a Undefined index: numbers error.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="numbers"/>
    <div><input type="submit" value="submit"></div>
</form>

<?php

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $arrayNums = explode(",", $_GET['numbers']);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that - didn't work

Comment: "Be welcoming and patient, especially with those who may not know everything you do"

Answer (score 2):

```
    <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="numbers"/>
    <div><input type="submit" value="submit"></div>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['numbers']))
{
    $arrayNums = explode(",", $_POST['numbers']);
    var_dump($arrayNums);
}

?>
```

Submitting a form will not pass a submit value in your html designed.
Instead, you could check for the numbers that are posted.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `$_POST[]` superglobal if you are posting the form data to the server and not `$_GET[]`.